# Saving form data to a variable (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, c#, php, .net, html

I am trying to take user input from a form on my webpage and assign that to a variable. Trying to take the user input as an integer and plug it into an algorithm that will display an answer on the screen. I've searched all over the internet and have not been able to figure it out.

Synopsis:

Retrieve as a userInput from a form and save it as an integer to a variable to be used as inputs to an algorithm. With an output to the screen also as an integer.

***LocalStorage does not allow you to assign userInput to a variable. It only allows you to save the session state without using cookies.
***val also does not allow you to assign userInput to a variable it only allows the webpage to know what the user is selecting.

Comment: Why not use LocalStorage?

Comment: See my answer on the duplicate to learn how to implement for the form stuff.

Comment: I looked into local storage, but it seems like that is used to make it easier to save data for personal preferences basically like what cookies used to be for.

Comment: True that. But your question is totally unclear. AFAIK I would say to use `LocalStorage` until you explain your issue clearly. Can you please tell us, what you have done, where you are struggling to get what?

Comment: Have you tried using jquery `val()` http://api.jquery.com/val/?

Comment: Basically I have a program that I wrote in Java for calculating how much the company will make based on charging different interest rates. They have used it for sometime now, but they want something they can open up in a web browser. I thought this would be easy, but as it turns out it can get a little complicated. I want two boxes that they can input how much it costs the company and how much interest they want to negotiate. This then gets put into a basic algorithm and provides an output. However, I haven't figured out how to do this.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, Nora. I will check this out.